# Как просмотреть функции из user32.dll?

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2010

Пробовал через `DUMPBIN`, выдает "невозможно открыть".

Проект на C#, если это важно.

Answer (score 1):

Открой тоталкомандер, найди свою dll и нажми F3

Answer (score 0):

с какой целью посмотреть? если просто глянуть зависимости и список внешних функций то я использую для этого dependency walker